# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Load balance across servers

Tags: asp.net-core, load-balancing, asp.net-core-2.0

I have my site load balanced across 10 servers.  It seems when the user gets switched between servers they have to log back in.  I am storing my machine keys and Session state in Redis.  The .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie exists and is not expired when they get logged out.  It seems that a cookie generated on one server is not being accepted on a different server.  Is there another setting I need to set for Load balancing?

This is my ConfigureServices code.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<Implementation.Core.IdentityUser, Implementation.Core.IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserStore<Implementation.UserStore<Implementation.Core.IdentityUser, 
                                                   Implementation.Core.IdentityRole, 
                                                   Implementation.Core.UserClaim, 
                                                   Implementation.Core.UserLogin, 
                                                   Implementation.Core.UserRole>>()
            .AddRoleStore<Implementation.RoleStore<Implementation.Core.IdentityRole>>();

    services.AddScoped<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher<Implementation.Core.IdentityUser>, Implementation.PasswordHasher>();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "RedirectUrl";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Login/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/AccessDenied";
            });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
    {
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Controllers.LocationController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SysAdmin.Controllers.CommandController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Supplier.Controllers.SupplierLocationController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SpectacleCatalog.Controllers.LensDesignController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Account.Controllers.CBUSearchController).Assembly);

    //services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();


    OutOfStateSettings outOfState = new OutOfStateSettings();
    Configuration.Bind("OutOfState", outOfState);

    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(opts =>
    {
        opts.Configuration = outOfState.RedisIP;
        opts.InstanceName = outOfState.CacheId;
    });

    var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{outOfState.RedisIP}:{outOfState.RedisPort}");
    services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToRedis(redis, outOfState.MachineKeyId);
    services.AddOptions();

    services.AddSingleton<
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.IValidationAttributeAdapterProvider,
        Util.CustomValidatiomAttributeAdapterProvider>();

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
    });

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);
    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}
```

Comment: What load balancer are you using? A common practice is to do "sticky sessions" on the load balancer. A user sent to one server behind the balancer will always be sent on that one

Comment: I am turning sticky back on for now but would like to have the load distributed among all 10 servers.  We are using F5 load balancers.

Comment: Take a read of [How to Set Up ASP.NET Core DataProtection in a Web Farm](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2016/06/15/set-up-asp-net-dataprotection-in-a-farm/) for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same machine key then it should work properly. 
How many Redis servers you are using? all are in cluster? 
Some  Redis server cluster not set properly this can be happen.

But in general try to avoid sessions if you need scalability. You can use claims to store some information instead of Session

Comment: Right now just one redis server.  I just looked at the CreationDate and it was created today.  Do the keys get overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem sometime ago. It turns out I was using a Memory based cache (which is machine specific) as a primary with Redis as the secondary. So the keys were sometimes ONLY cached in memory.

So just confirm that its not a similar case for you.

Good lucky though!